# Open Settings > Passwords & Accounts > Add Account from my iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, openurl

I want to add google calendars to my system calendars.
And then using EventStore kit just read all events I am interested in.
At some step I need to open from my app "setting > account & password > add account" so that I could use google calendars though EventStore

So, how can I open the setting screen from my ios app?

Answer (score 0):

iOS 11 and later, use:

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!)
```

Comment: It just opening Setting screen or the last have opened setting screen.
But how to open the exact "setting > passwords & account > add account" screen

Comment: Ok, Let me make it clear.
You can add account, google, outlook, exchange e.t.c and share from that newly added account mails, calendars, contacts.
If you share calendars for instance and open your system calendar you will see calendars from google account.